# How to upload files to a Windows Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to publish a package that has 800mb+. But the Windows Azure publish only allows up to 600mb, so maybe I need to upload some unstructured files first to Windows Azure storage.

What's the best way to upload files to a Windows Azure storage?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> what's the best way to upload files to a windows azure storage?

There's no *best way* - you'll need to decide that for yourself. But... here are a few options:

- Create an app, using one of the language SDKs (.NET, PHP, Ruby, Java, Node, Python, Node). The SDKs each have coverage of blob storage, allowing you to create an upload app. You could also make direct REST API calls instead of using the SDK. You'll find many examples of this around the web, including [this .NET sample](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs-20/#upload-blob) on the [Azure.com](http://www.azure.com) site.
- Call the PowerShell command `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`, which copies a local file to a blob
- Call the Azure cross-platform CLI command `azure storage blob upload`, which copies a local file to a blob
- Use a storage copy tool. The Azure team provides [AzCopy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/azcopy-transfer-data-with-re-startable-mode-and-sas-token.aspx). There are 3rd-party tools as well. The Azure Storage team recently [blogged](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/03/11/windows-azure-storage-explorers-2014.aspx) about various 3rd-party tools available.

Comment: thanks for the response @David, i was able to upload files using option 1 :) just had to do little search to study how.

Answer (score 19):

Another way is: http://storageexplorer.com/

To Upload files:

1. Select the Container
2. Open the "Blob Container Editor"
3. Click Upload for Files and Folders

[image]

Comment: Too bad it does not support the upload of multiple folders... I need to upload a folder with Episerver media, which includes dozens of folders. Too much manual job.

Comment: Your best bet there is probably going to be a powershell script  and azure powershell commands or AzCopy.

Azure Powershell info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-powershell-guide-full

AzCopy info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion to help you might be to upload the files with help of the UploadFromStream() method in the blobs storage SDK. To implement this method, you need to know the Container Name, Archive Storage Account, and Storage Key.

As the method demands the usage of custom coding, you can leverage third-party tools like Cerebrata (https://cerebrata.com/). The tool basically allows you to upload files of any size and also provides options to customize the chunk size, overwrite behavior, file extension, and block blob access tier.

[upload files - Azure Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzZuM.gif)

Answer (score -3):

Used ftp client i.e filezilla client to upload files from client to remote machine
Note : first create ftp credentials in azure.

Comment: You cannot use ftp to upload content to Azure Storage. You're thinking of storage within a virtual machine, which is not what the OP asked about.